# Evaluating the performance gain from multi-threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to compare the performance gain from parallel computing using multithreading module and the normal sequence computing but couldn't find any real difference. Here's what I did:

```
import time, threading, Queue
q=Queue.Queue()

def calc(_range):
    exponent=(x**5 for x in _range)
    q.put([x**0.5 for x in exponent])

def calc1(_range):
    exponent=(x**5 for x in _range)
    return [x**0.5 for x in exponent]

def multithreds(threadlist):
    d=[]
    for x in threadlist:
        t=threading.Thread(target=calc, args=([x]))
        t.start()
        t.join()
        s=q.get()
        d.append(s)
    return d


threads=[range(100000), range(200000)]

start=time.time()
#out=multithreads(threads)
out1=[calc1(x)for x in threads]
end=time.time()
print end-start
```

Timing using threading:`0.9390001297`
Timing running in sequence:`0.911999940872`

The timing running in sequence was constantly lower than using multithreading.
I have a feeling there's something wrong with my multithreading code.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have two `calc` functions?

Comment: One of them is for the multithreading as I wanted the output returned in a  queue. Hence I used one for threading, and the other for sequence.

Comment: Consider a more expensive function call - `fork`ing or starting threads isn't free, so for very small calls, the initializing overhead is very non-trivial compared to the actual "work."

Comment: @tristan, I think `os.fork` is too expensive for my main task. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the overhead you're going to incur going with native threads or processes is going to be very large for such a small amount of work.  I'd suggest looking into native threads for potential improvement

Answer (score 1):

The reference implementation of Python (CPython) has a so-called interpreter lock where always one thread executes Python byte-code. You can switch for example to IronPython which has no GIL or you can take a look at the multiprocessing module which spawns several Python processes which can execute your code independently. In some scenarios using threads in Python can even be slower than a single-thread because the context-switches between threads on the CPU also introduce some overhead.

Take a look [at this page](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/multicore_python.html) for some deeper insights and help.

If you want to dive much more deeper in this topic I can highly recommend [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s) by David Beazley.

Comment: I'll consider IronPython as for some reason I can't import multiprocessing module. However, as long as there's threading in CPython, then multithreading is possible. I believe there's a way out. Thanks.

Comment: I tried importing multiprocessing module but got this error message:  'no module named dummy'. However I checked the multiprocessing file at the python directory and found dummy. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Multithreading is possible in CPython, but getting a speedup from multiple cores via multithreading is unlikely, due to the GIL.